# Symfony Mock a specific method in my unit test

Tags: php, symfony, testing, mocking, phpunit

I have problem when trying to mock a service in order to unit test it.

in my test class I have,

```
    $mock = $this->getMock('MyClass');
    $mock->expects($this->any())->method('method_2')->will($this->returnValue('fake_value'));
```

in my service, **method_2()** calls another method (let's say **method_1()**')

As I want to unit test only **method_1()** I need to mock only **method_2()**
but when I am running this test, **method_1()** already returns null.

Do you have any idea on why I'm already getting null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [getMock() helper signature](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php), it allows you to pass an array of methods as a second argument, those methods are then mocked and returns `null` (unless you define the valus each one of them should return)

In your case all the methods are mocked and return `null` except `method_2()` for which you forced the returned value.

Try again and replace,

```
$mock = $this->getMock('MyClass');
```

by,

```
$mock = $this->getMock('MyClass', array('method_2'));
```